# What is the difference for sample/resample/scale/resize/adaptive-resize/thumbnail operators in ImageMagick convert?

Tags: imagemagick, thumbnails

I found multiple ways to change the resolution of an image using `convert`:

```
-sample
-resample
-scale
-resize
-adaptive-resize
-thumbnail
```

What's the difference of those?

If I need to make various size large picture thumbnail with fixed aspect ratio (cropping needed) -- what's my best choice?

Comment: This URL - [ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Resize or Scaling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) should help you.

Comment: For even more information, see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/ and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/

Answer (score 160, accepted):

**resize**

> **`-resize 400x300+20+30`** (like the `-scale` and `-sample` examples below) converts an input to an output image which has the pixel dimensions of `400x300`. It also shifts the output by 20 pixels to the right and by 30 pixels to the bottom. Additionally, there are a few more differences to `-scale`:

- `-resize` does support an additional setting of `-filter` (which should occur on the commandline *before* using `-resize`!).
- `-filter` determines the exact algorithm to be used for the colors of added pixels in the case of magnification, or for the colors to be used for the remaining pixels when some of their neighbors are removed in case of minification.
- For a list of supported filters, simply run `convert -list filter`.
- `-filter point -resize 400x300` creates exactly the same result as `-sample 400x300` does, but it runs still a bit slower.
- If not set alongside (before) `-resize`, the conversion will silently default to `-filter Lanczos` which is slower, but which generates a much better quality (because it takes into account the colors of all surrounding pixels for any newly added ones) than `-filter point` produces (which uses the *nearest neighbor* rule to determine the color of a newly added pixels).

**sample**

> **`-sample 400x300`** converts an input image to an output images which has the pixel dimensions of `400x300`. However, there are a few very important differences to `-resize`:

- `-sample` does not support the additional setting of `-filter`; if set anyway, then `-filter` is simply ignored.
- When magnifying (because the input image size may be smaller than `400x300`), pixels are replicated in blocks.
- When minifying (because the input image size may be larger than `400x300`), pixels are sub-sampled with a very simple algorithm: some rows and columns are simply skipped over.
- The *geometry* argument to `-sample` doesn't support any *offset* part (unlike `-resize`, which respects *offset* directives for the output).
- The output will never have more (different) colors than the input image had; it may have fewer colors though.
- Therefore `-sample` is very fast (faster than `-resize`) -- but output quality is (usually) worse: you can easily get extreme [blocking](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#blocking) and [aliasing](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#aliasing) effects in the resulting output.
- One important feature of `-sample` is that the new image will not contain any new colors, though some colors from the original image may disappear.

**resample**

> **`-resample`** uses as parameter the desired `XxY` ***resolution***, not not the `XxY` pixel ***geometry*** of the target image. The purpose of this operator is to preserve the *rendered* size of an image: Assume your image measures 4 inches by 3 inches on a device that renders it at 300 DPI. Then asking for a `-resample 72` or `-resample 72x72` will resize the image so that it measures (again) 4 inches by 3 inches on a 72 DPI device.

- This operation works only for such images which already have a desired resolution stored in their metadata (not all image formats do support the concept of an image resolution -- JPEG, PNG and TIFF do).
- If the source image is in a format where internal support for an image resolution is missing, then the (assumed) original resolution of the image must be specified via `-density` on the command line *prior* to specifying the `-resample` resolution.

**scale**

> **`-scale 400x300`** produces the equivalent result (but is faster, because it avoids all the filter processing) as does using `-filter box -resize 400x300`. It also completely ignores any current `-filter` setting.

- When minifying, it changes the image size simply by replacing pixel colors by averaging the respective input pixel colors together.
- When magnifying, it simply replicates the respective input pixels for the required additional pixels.

**adaptive-resize**

> **`-adaptive-resize 400x300`** does not support (or does ignore, if set) the *offset* part of a *geometry* parameter and also ignores the `-gravity` setting if present.

- It uses by default [*data-dependent triangulation*](http://web.archive.org/web/20170813055734/http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/%7Epjw/Q3D/forum-ddt.pdf) when resizing (unless the resize method is overridden by additionally specifying `-filter [something]`).

**thumbnail**

> **`-thumbnail`** works just like `-resize` does, with a few differences:

- It is optimized for speed.
- It also removes any embedded color profiles to reduce the filesize of the thumbnails.

---

The following answer shows a few (illustrated!) examples of the `-resize` directive. Each illustration shows a different result, depending on the 'fine details' of the exact resize method:

- [**ImageMagick crop command not giving perfect result**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11721339/359307)

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much more sense than the ImageMagick documentation.

Comment: If you had sample images, this would be even more perfect :-)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: First of all, thank you for the highly informative answer. Please, can you suggest any good book or a documentation pdf for Imagemagick. The best approach I have right now is scrape all pages of Imagemagick to reduce reading time, but it's a lot of information(which in my opinion, not always descriptive enough). Any help is high appreciated.

Comment: I know it's been a minute but I just wanted to let you know how useful this answer has been.  Do you happen to know if any of this has changed with recent versions of `ImageMagick`?