# Imagemagick Crop command not giving perfect result

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using Imagemagick for resizing and cropping image.

Test Image :

[image]

I need to re-size it for 300 x 320 frame for this first I am resizing the image and then cropping it and i am using the following commands:

```
exec("convert /uploadImagePath -thumbnail  300  /newImagePath");

exec("convert /newImagePath -gravity Center -crop 290x310+0+0 /newImagePath");
```

But it gives me following image

[image]

As you can see image is not complete. Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$inputFile = "WPTgp.jpg";
exec("convert {$inputFile} -resize 290x310^ -gravity Center -crop 290x310+0+0 picCropped.png");
```

Comment: I have ImageMagick 6.7.6-9 on my local machine and above command give me perfect result but when i upload it to server which has ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 version and result is not same as local machine any idea ?

Comment: @Muhammad Umair: I honestly don't understand why this is the accepted answer. **It doesn't work as required** by the question -- it **does crop the image**, and does so very badly!

Answer (score 52):

**(Answer is updated, providing an illustrated example for `-liquid-rescale` further below now)**

---

Your original image's dimensions are:

```
489 x 640 pixels
```

Your desired dimensions seem to be:

```
290 x 310 pixels
```

This cannot scale to these dimensions without either:

1. cropping (do not keep all areas of the intial image)
2. keeping desired width (give up desired height)
3. keeping desired height (give up desired width)
4. distortion (do not keep the aspect ratio when scaling)
5. padding (add more pixels to one or more edges)
6. removing pixels where it's not obvious ("liquid rescale" or "seam carving" -- [**see Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving))

Your result shows '1.' (cropping), which you don't like. So you have options '2.' (keeping width), '3.' (keeping height), '4.' (distortion), '5.' (padding) and '6.' (seam carving) left to test.

### '2.': Keeping desired Height

```
convert WPTgp.jpg -resize x310 keep-height.jpg
```

Resulting Image has dimensions of `237 x 310 pixels`.
**`Keep Height....`** [image: Keep Height]
(determine width automatically)

### '3.': Keeping desired Width

```
convert WPTgp.jpg -resize 290x keep-width.jpg
```

Resulting Image has dimensions of `290 x 380 pixels`.
**`Keep Width.....`** [image: Keep Width]
(determine height automatically)

### '4.': Distortion

```
convert WPTgp.jpg -resize 290x310\! distorted.jpg
```

Resulting Image has dimensions of `290 x 310 pixels`.
**`Distorted......`** [image: Distorted]
(ignore aspect ratio -- distort image if required to fit dimensions)

### '5.': Padding

```
convert WPTgp.jpg \
   -resize 290x310 \
   -gravity center \
   -background orange \
   -extent 290x310 \
    padded.jpg
```

Resulting Image has dimensions of `290 x 310 pixels`. (Orange background was added only to demonstrate that the 'extention' of the image did work.)
**`Padded.........`** [image: Padded]
(keep aspect ratio -- extend image for desired dimensions)

### '6.': Seam Carving

```
convert WPTgp.jpg -liquid-rescale 290x310\! liquid.jpg
```

The above would be the command you'd spontaneously derive from quick-reading the ImageMagick command options reference. However, it doesn't work well, and instead I used:

```
convert WPTgp.jpg -liquid-rescale 599x640\! -scale 290x310 liquid.jpg
convert WPTgp.jpg -liquid-rescale 599x640\! -scale 48.4%   liquid.jpg
```

Further below is an explanation why I needed to modify it....
**`Liquid-rescaled`** [image: 'Liquidly' rescaled]
<strike>Sorry -- I cannot provide example picture right now; this requires the additional ImageMagick delegate `liblqr` (liquid rescaling library) to be installed, which I don't have at this moment)</strike>  I've now had the opportunity to create a 'liquidly rescaled' version of the original image.

---

### Caveats about Seam Carving / `'-liquid-rescale'`:

As stated above, the last image is **not** the result of my originally proposed command, but of one of these two modified versions:

```
convert WPTgp.jpg -liquid-rescale 599x640\! -scale 290x310 liquid.jpg
convert WPTgp.jpg -liquid-rescale 599x640\! -scale 48.4%   liquid.jpg
```

Remember, we have an original image of 489x610 pixels, which we are expected to scale to 290x310 pixels. But `-liquid-rescale` isn't good at rescaling in two dimensions at once -- it's designed to scale into one direction only (horizontal or vertical). If you try to do both at once, results may not be what you'd expect. Here is the result for the originally proposed command:

```
 convert WPTgp.jpg -liquid-rescale 290x310\! liquid.jpg
```

**`LQR gone wrong`** [image: liquid-rescale gone wrong]

That's why I came up with the two modified commands which work in two steps:

1. First, apply liquid rescaling to the horizontal dimension only, expanding the original's width from 489 pixels to 599 pixels.
2. Second, apply 'normal' aspect-ratio-keeping scaling to the intermediate result to produce the final image.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair please accept this nicely crafted answer